# Can't access share folder on a different vlan with a windows 10 in a domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, share, vlan

i share un folder on a pc under windows 10 on a vlan. I had rules on his firewall in order to allow access from a windows 10 computer on a different vlan.

I can effectivly access to the folder via a windows 10 computer on a distinct vlan, but when i connect the pc to the domain it is impossible to access the share folder and no gpo are applyed on the computer. If i stop the firewall nothing change

do you have any idea ?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

on domain member, "Guest" account must be enable and "Everyone" group granted access to your share and folder.
have a look to https://serverfault.com/questions/51635/how-can-an-unauthenticated-user-access-a-windows-share